# Decimal in input JSON to Python 3 Lambda Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, aws-lambda

Consider the following input in a financial application, where precision matters:

`{  "value": 3.8 }`

And the following AWS Lambda function:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    value = event['value']
    print(Decimal(value))
```

The output is: `3.79999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875` because Python parsed the number in the JSON into a float, which can't precisely store 3.8.

I know that I can serialize `event` back to a string and then instruct the parser to use Decimal (this is from the [DynamoDB Python docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.02.html)):

```
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    parsed = json.loads(json.dumps(event), parse_float=Decimal)
    print(Decimal(parsed['value']))
```

But that feels like a hack. Is there some way to control the deserialization in the first place so that `event` prefers Decimal to float?

Comment: Please provide complete (running) code. Try to print value and not Decimal(value), Decimal(value) may get casted to a float.

Comment: This is complete, running code. I was copy/pasting from the AWS Lambda console. I need a Decimal later in the code for other reasons, but the print demonstrates the problem.

Comment: When I say "other reasons," I mean, that rounding is not acceptable. E.g., `Decimal(3.8)*Decimal(10)` returns 37.99999999999999822364316060. No bueno in a financial application.

Comment: If you always wish to round to cents, it might be easier to store such values as **integers in cents**. This way, there will never be a partial-cent: `380 * 10 = 3800`

Comment: I meant code that one can copy paste and run. Maybe put ```json.loads(json.dumps(event), parse_float=Decimal)``` in a function so that the code looks at a bit better. Maybe you can change but you will have to look where the event object is created. Maybe Sympy can help you. Good luck.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein clever idea. Assume in this case I need fractional cents of arbitrary precision (e.g. accumulate micro payments to a monthly payment). 
@cgte In this case, I'm not sure a running command line example is possible, since how AWS Lambda parses the incoming JSON into `event` is an essential part of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** There is nothing wrong with your current solution.

There is no `float` to `str` to `decimal.Decimal` round-trip.

As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.load) explain (my emphasis):

> *parse_float*, if specified, will be called **with the string** of every JSON float to be decoded. By default, this is equivalent to
>   float(num_str). This can be used to use another datatype or parser for
>   JSON floats (e.g. [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal)).

---

**Initial answer below**

Passing a `float` value to `decimal.Decimal` does not ensure the precision you require. This is because, by its nature, `float` is not stored as a decimal but in binary.

This can be alleviated if you are able to pass string inputs into `decimal.Decimal`:

```
from decimal import Decimal

res1 = Decimal(3.8)*Decimal(10)
res2 = Decimal('3.8')*Decimal('10')

print(res1)  # 37.99999999999999822364316060
print(res2)  # 38.0
```

So one solution would be to ensure you store / read in JSON numeric data as strings instead of floats.

Be careful, an implementation as below may work *but* relies on `str` doing a particular job, i.e. rounding a `float` correctly for decimal representation.

```
def lambda_handler(event):
    value = event['value']
    print(Decimal(str(value)))

lambda_handler({"value": 3.8})  # 3.8
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is essentially what my `json.dumps` -> `json.loads` hack does. As you say, it relies on a black box to print strings from floats in a particular way. I think the problem here is the way Lambda parses the JSON into the `event` dict and decides that `value` is a float and not a Decimal.

Comment: @TravisPettijohn, Yep, I'm sorry I don't know a better solution. Hopefully someone can enlighten us. Or we offer a bounty to get some more attention in a couple of days.

Comment: @TravisPettijohn, We did a bit more research. It seems your solution is *not* a hack. I've added a reference to the documentation to explain. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for the additional digging. I'm not sure I agree. I interpret the documentation you reference as describing how json.loads() works: `json.loads('{  "value": 3.8 }', parse_float=Decimal)` uses the string value - that is, calls `Decimal("3.8")` to handle the number in JSON. There's still ambiguity on how Lambda handles floats (we know it uses float, not Decimal), and how `json.dumps(event)` converts those numbers to strings.

Comment: `Decimal('3.8')` is exactly what we need, though, right? This is recommended by the `decimal` docs and guarantees you have no rounding issues. What we *don't* want is `Decimal(str(3.8))`.

Comment: In the Lambda handler, type(event['value']) == float. That's the root of the problem I'm hoping to solve, it has already been parsed into a float.