# How to take a float value as an input in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to pass a float value in AWS lambda as a key, value pair in the event and for that I am doing

```
from decimal import Decimal
ENERGY_VERBRAUCH = event['energy_verbrauch']
ENERGY_VERBRAUCH = Decimal(str(ENERGY_VERBRAUCH))
```

and my key, value pair in the event is

```
"energy_verbrauch": "2500000"
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
START RequestId: e2179e21-f225-44a1-bb99-266b184bc4e2 Version: $LATEST
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'
END RequestId: e2179e21-f225-44a1-bb99-266b184bc4e2
```

and the log:

[image]

I looked into an already existing question on SO and followed that, but still, I get the error.

The question: [Decimal in input JSON to Python 3 Lambda Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282080/decimal-in-input-json-to-python-3-lambda-function)

The `ENERGY_VERBRAUCH` is then passed on to a function

```
def factorize(energy_needed, df):
    '''For scaling the Lastprofile on energy verbrauch'''
    factor = energy_needed/(df['values'].sum()/1000)
    df['values'] = (df['values']/1000)*factor
    df['values'] = df['values'].round(3)
    return df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, `Decimal` values do not support division with `float` values.

> my key, value pair in the event is
>
> ```
> "energy_verbrauch": "2500000"
> ```

This is an integer value. In this case using `Decimal` seems unnecessary.

You can just change

> ```
> from decimal import Decimal
> ENERGY_VERBRAUCH = event['energy_verbrauch']
> ENERGY_VERBRAUCH = Decimal(str(ENERGY_VERBRAUCH))
> ```

to

```
ENERGY_VERBRAUCH = int(event['energy_verbrauch'])
```

(You also do not need to use `str`, as the value is already a string.)

Then the division will be between an `int` and a `float`, which is allowed and will result in another `float`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `energy_needed` is the Decimal your passing in your method

At this line you're doing a division between a decimal and a float.

```
factor = energy_needed/(df['values'].sum()/1000)
```

You need to convert it to Decimal

```
factor = energy_needed/Decimal(df['values'].sum()/1000)
```

Now **factor** is `Decimal` and you'll need to keep converting other operands when using it in an operation.